# How to call an Oracle procedure within a package?

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

I'm trying to call an Oracle stored procedure within a package and I'm getting this error:
SQL Error: ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name

I'm using SQL Developer and this is the command I'm using

```
call WEATHERDATAUPDATES.GetLastRunDate("WeatherData")
```

Here is the package/procedure

```
PACKAGE BODY WEATHERDATAUPDATES AS

  PROCEDURE GetLastRunDate(PROCESS IN VARCHAR2, RUNDATE OUT DATE) AS
  BEGIN
    SELECT rundate FROM Marcie.last_rundate
    where process = PROCESS;
  END GetLastRunDate;

END WEATHERDATAUPDATES;
```

I'm pretty new to Oracle Packages and not sure what I'm missing.  I tried searching, but can't find an answer that works.  Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks,
Marcie

Answer (score 4):

GetLastRunDate has 2 parameters, (process and rundate), but you're only passing 1 in your call.

Since you want to pass the second parameter out, one option would be to make it function and return the rundate.

```
PACKAGE BODY WEATHERDATAUPDATES AS

  FUNCTION GetLastRunDate(PROCESS IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN DATE
  AS
     lDate DATE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT rundate
    INTO   lDate
    FROM   Marcie.last_rundate
    where  process = PROCESS;

    RETURN lDate;
  END GetLastRunDate;

END WEATHERDATAUPDATES;
```

Comment: I think it may be an authority issue as well.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4):

In your procedure you are not putting the retrieved value anywhere, you should use `INTO`:

```
...    
   PROCEDURE GetLastRunDate(PROCESS IN VARCHAR2, RUNDATE OUT DATE) AS
   BEGIN
     SELECT rundate 
     INTO RUNDATE 
     FROM Marcie.last_rundate  
     where process = PROCESS;
   END GetLastRunDate;
...
```

In the call pass the variable for the out parameter `RUNDATE OUT DATE`.

Put the call in a PL/SQL block:

```
DECLARE
    lastRunDate DATE;
BEGIN
    WEATHERDATAUPDATES.GetLastRunDate("WeatherData",lastRunDate);   
    -- do something with lastRunDate
END;
```

Comment: I think it may be an authority issue as well.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

You have shown the BODY of your package, but not the specification - check that `GetLastRunDate` is declared in the package spec.

Comment: Yes you are right, if it is declared only in body, then calling a procedure from outside may not be possible at all. It is available only inside the package.